# Should biology.SE be the primary source for troubleshooting for iGEM?

Tags: discussion

It's iGEM season and there are a lot of troubled undergrads trying to do experiments. Should we be advertising to those folks?

Answer (score 3):

Because the participants compete to win the competition by coming up with the best idea/design (I'm not that familiar with iGEM, but this is what I gather) then surely aiding in the design would be unfair. However questions with a more broad biological context (i.e. general info, rather than help with a specific experiment they wish to try) could be seen as OK?

Although, homework questions are permitted, so long as the poster can show that they have put a reasonable about of work in themselves. This same criteria could apply?